# Visualizing Python interactive plots outside of Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am making some small tests in Jupyter. The user should see two plots, one on the left and one on the right. Than after clicking somewhere on the left plot something on the right plot should happen. For example here a click on the left plot will produce a red dot on the right plot in the same place:

```
%matplotlib notebook


def onclick(event):    
    ax.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(0,10)
    ax.set_ylim(0,10)
    ax2.set_xlim(0,10)
    ax2.set_ylim(0,10)
    ax2.plot([event.xdata],[event.ydata],'o',color='red')
    ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
    ax2.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))


ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax2.set_xlim(0,10)
ax2.set_ylim(0,10)


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
```

This works, but the visualization in Jupyter is not the best. Is there a way to have this kind of interactive plots working outside of a Jupyter notebook ? Maybe in a window with varying dimensions ? As an example, how would one proceed with the example above ?

Comment: What do you specifically mean by outside of Jupyter? Is JupyterLite's REPL acceptable? See https://twitter.com/jtpio/status/1442486540538560522 for some displaying interactive plots. Or with pyscript, like [here](https://twitter.com/EduardoBonet/status/1521841937233465345) or [first bokeh example listed here](https://pyscript.net/examples/). (it's interactive despite what it says). Would ones made in Jupyter and then served still interactively via nbviewer be acceptable? Such as [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/Plotly3d-scatter-plots.ipynb)?

Comment: Or does Voila meet you needs for being "outside Jupyter"? See [Voila Gallery](https://voila-gallery.org/).

Comment: I am not sure... Essentially in the example above I would like the figures that would appear in a jupyter notebook after executing the cells in a standalone window, without the code. This standalone window should "serve the python code" and could also run in a browser (why not?). I wonder if "flask" is maybe the way to go.

Comment: It is important for me that python libraries are supported (in particular opencv) and that the plots remain interactive.

Comment: Voila and [appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) hide the code by default. For a Voila example where I select what to plot go to [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and click `'launch binder'`. Then from the available demonstrations choose `'streamlined 3D scatter plot in Voila interface'`. Basically the one listed before that explains how it works and shows the code in notebook mode. Your needs sound different but I think Voila combined with Matplotlib or Plotly could cover your needs. Appmode is a little easier to learn and implement for simple cases though.

Comment: Voila usually requires everything to be in ipywidgets form, which can be a little harder to implement if you haven't tried them before.

Comment: From the examples you gave, indeed Voila seems close to what I would like to have. If you find a way to modify the code I wrote into a voila application that would be great :) . In the final application I should be able to call ax.imshow(image) and modify the content of the "image" according to the click of the user. This I am already able to do it inside a jupyter notebook but from what you say I am not sure the code can be easily ported to be voila compatible...

Comment: Anyway, I will also try and see what I manage to do...

Comment: Indeed I tried the code above with Voila and it does not work

Comment: So as far as I understand event picking as implemented in matplotlib https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html is not compatible with voila. What would be the alternatives to get the position of a mouse click ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245021/discussion-between-thomas-and-wayne).

Answer (score 1):

You can use plotly and export your plots to html file:

https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/

Comment: This sounds a nice solution (+1). Even if this requires some refactoring of the code. E.g. the one in the original post cannot be reused. I wonder what is compatible with this approach though. In my case according to a click in the left image the right one is modified using opencv routines. Can plotly also convert opencv routines to javascript or should I also rewrite all the analysis code with plotly routines?

Comment: ( check also discussion in the chat,if you are interested in providing more help )

Comment: Anyway, as a start, if you know how to have the effect of the initial post using plotly let me know at the moment I was not able to replicate it

Comment: if you can provide some slice of data and some (image) example of plot you want, i can refactore and format it to you

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a possible simple answer to my needs. Simply put the code in the question in a python script, remove the 'magic' command and insert at the end:

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

This way matplotlib will just use a different backend than notebook or inline in Jupiter and plot the figure in a separate window. This window is compatible with the interactive commands from matplotlib. I am not sure about widget compatibility though I will try and update the answer.

Update: I do not think ipywidgets can be used with plt.show() since these are not plotted in an axes, but there are some widgets within matplotlib (matplotlib.widgets) that can be used. Though, the resulting speed in my case is not satisfactory so I would avoid combining matplotlib widgets with matplotlib event catching.